# Model for a multithreaded/forked server daemon

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, daemon

I'm developing a database-connected Linux daemon in C++ that will act as a "server" for some networked controller devices. It has to have some form of concurrency to be able to service multiple devices at the same time. The server will listen for incoming connections and fork/thread/select()/whatever for each connected device. This connection should remain open until it drops or is closed. The clients will not be multithreaded, so they may only have one connection at a time.

This project requires a device to be able to contact the "server" with a command that will be processed, often including database queries, and, in turn, send a command to another one of the networked devices. The database query will determine which of the other clients to talk to. I then have to find which process or thread it's attached to and communicate with the device through the existing connection to that thread.

Think of some form of "authorization" at one device causing another device to receive a command and do something. I can't just send the commands "peer-to-peer" between devices because everything has to be logged at the server and database queries may be necessary.

I'm perplexed by the communication between threads/processes. I anticipate having a class for the client (i.e. `Device`) and creating an object in each separate process or thread. I know of named pipes & shared memory when using fork(), as well as techniques for communicating with other threads, but I worry about synchronization and potential stability concerns. I was excited about fork and its ease of use and simplicity until I hit this issue. Stability is the #1 concern.

Am I doing this totally wrong? My description isn't exactly great, so those of you who think you might be able to help probably will have to ask questions first. Maybe someone just finished building something exactly like this...

---

I apologize both for the length of this question and the rather vague nature. It's more of a design question rather than a direct, answerable one. I wasn't sure if it belonged at Programmers or here at SO. Feel free to move if necessary.

Thank you to everyone who attempts to save my sanity.

**Update**: If I'm using Boost.Asio for this, can anyone give me a brief explanation/sample code or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ahve a look at Boost::Asio and at the active object patterm.
There is a nice video/talk about this very subject at boost'Con 2010 that you can find on blip.tvB